# jQuery dnd file upload for multiple targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using ***[jQuery dnd file upload plugin](http://code.google.com/p/dnd-file-upload/)*** for a project. All example of dnd uploader use `id` as a selector. For multiple items they used different `dropzone` declaration.

How can I change the plugin setting for multiple `dropzone` where the selector will be a `class` or something else to grab multiple elements with a single `dropzone` initiation?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is using jQuery, couldn't you use the standard jQuery multiple selector method? It would look like this:

```
$("#drop1, #drop2, #drop3").dropzone();
```

Or if you are trying to do a class, you would do this:

```
$(".drop_zone").dropzone();
```

This isn't tested, and I have never used this plugin. I'm just assuming this would work since it is based off jQuery.

Since that isn't working, try replacing the code for jquery.dnd-file-upload.js with the following:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.dropzone = function (options) {
var opts = {};
var uploadFiles = function (files) {
$.fn.dropzone.newFilesDropped(); for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
var file = filesi?;
// create a new xhr object var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); var upload = xhr.upload; upload.fileIndex = i; upload.fileObj = file; upload.downloadStartTime = new Date().getTime(); upload.currentStart = upload.downloadStartTime; upload.currentProgress = 0; upload.startData = 0;
// add listeners upload.addEventListener("progress", progress, false);
xhr.onload = function (event) {
load(event, xhr);
};
xhr.open(opts.method, opts.url); xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"); xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.fileName); xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.fileSize); xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); xhr.send(file);
$.fn.dropzone.uploadStarted(i, file);
}
};
var drop = function (event) {
var dt = event.dataTransfer; var files = dt.files;
event.preventDefault(); uploadFiles(files);
return false;
};
var log = function (logMsg) {
if (opts.printLogs) {
// console && console.log(logMsg);
}
};
// invoked when the input field has changed and new files have been dropped // or selected var change = function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
// get all files ... var files = this.files;
// ... and upload them uploadFiles(files);
};
var progress = function (event) {
if (event.lengthComputable) {
var percentage = Math.round((event.loaded 100) / event.total); if (this.currentProgress != percentage) {
// log(this.fileIndex + " --> " + percentage + "%");
this.currentProgress = percentage; $.fn.dropzone.fileUploadProgressUpdated(this.fileIndex, this.fileObj, this.currentProgress);
var elapsed = new Date().getTime(); var diffTime = elapsed - this.currentStart; if (diffTime >= opts.uploadRateRefreshTime) {
var diffData = event.loaded - this.startData; var speed = diffData / diffTime; // in KB/sec
$.fn.dropzone.fileUploadSpeedUpdated(this.fileIndex, this.fileObj, speed);
this.startData = event.loaded; this.currentStart = elapsed;
}
}
}
};
var load = function (event, xhr) {
var now = new Date().getTime(); var timeDiff = now - this.downloadStartTime; if (opts.onLoadComplete) {
opts.onLoadComplete(xhr.responseText);
} $.fn.dropzone.uploadFinished(this.fileIndex, this.fileObj, timeDiff); log("finished loading of file " + this.fileIndex);
};
var dragenter = function (event) {
event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); return false;
};
var dragover = function (event) {
event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); return false;
};
// Extend our default options with those provided. opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.dropzone.defaults, options);
var id = this.attr("id"); var dropzone = document.getElementById(id);
log("adding dnd-file-upload functionalities to element with id: " + id);
// hack for safari on windows: due to not supported drop/dragenter/dragover events we have to create a invisible <input type="file" /> tag instead if ($.client.browser == "Safari" && $.client.os == "Windows") {
var fileInput = $("<input>"); fileInput.attr({
type: "file"
}); fileInput.bind("change", change); fileInput.css({
'opacity': '0', 'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'
}); fileInput.attr("multiple", "multiple"); fileInput.click(function () {
return false;
}); this.append(fileInput);
} else {
dropzone.addEventListener("drop", drop, true); var jQueryDropzone = $("#" + id); jQueryDropzone.bind("dragenter", dragenter); jQueryDropzone.bind("dragover", dragover);
}
return this;
};
$.fn.dropzone.defaults = {
url: "", method: "POST", numConcurrentUploads: 3, printLogs: false, // update upload speed every second uploadRateRefreshTime: 1000
};
// invoked when new files are dropped $.fn.dropzone.newFilesDropped = function () { };
// invoked when the upload for given file has been started $.fn.dropzone.uploadStarted = function (fileIndex, file) { };
// invoked when the upload for given file has been finished $.fn.dropzone.uploadFinished = function (fileIndex, file, time) { };
// invoked when the progress for given file has changed $.fn.dropzone.fileUploadProgressUpdated = function (fileIndex, file,
newProgress) {
};
// invoked when the upload speed of given file has changed $.fn.dropzone.fileUploadSpeedUpdated = function (fileIndex, file,
KBperSecond) {
};
})(jQuery);
```

This was suggested by the user rik.leigh@gmail.com here http://code.google.com/p/dnd-file-upload/wiki/howto